# Объясните как работает данная строка в Java метод split

Tags: java

```
origin.split("[^a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разбить строку по символам которые не входят в a-zA-Zа-яА-Я. т.е. разбить строку не по буквам.

```
String [] s = "Я выйду на балкон".split("[^a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]")

s будет ["Я", "выйду", "на", "балкон"]
```